# Using a for loop with a function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops, for-loop

I am having trouble figuring out how to solve this challenge below:

**Challenge: droids**

Complete the function droids that accepts an array of strings and iterates through the array using a FOR loop. Update the variable result to "Found Droids!" if the array contains the string "Droids". Otherwise update the variable result to "These are not the droids you're looking for." Return your updated result.

Here is the code written so far:

```
function droids(arr) {
  let result = '';
  // ADD CODE HERE
  return result;
}

// Uncomment these to check your work! 
const starWars = ["Luke", "Finn", "Rey", "Kylo", "Droids"] 
 const thrones = ["Jon", "Danny", "Tyrion", "The Mountain", "Cersei"] 
 console.log(droids(starWars)) // should log: "Found Droids!"
 console.log(droids(thrones)) // should log: "These are not the droids you're looking for."
```

Can someone please help with find out what I need to add to solve this problem using javascript? Thank you so much

Comment: Have you looked up any tutorials or documentation on loops in JavaScript?

Comment: Just do `return arr.includes('Droids')` in your function. You don’t even need for loops.

Comment: here's how to use the [for statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for_statement) - hint: array indexes go from 0 to their length - 1 .... so `for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)` should get you started

Comment: @Terry ... *using a FOR loop* ... so, while that works, it's not answering his assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through `arr` and return `Found Droid` as soon as you find it, or if not found return with `not found`.

Simple approach as below.

```js
function droids(arr) {
  for(var str of arr) {
      if (str  === 'Droids') {
       return 'Found Droid';
    }
  }
 return `These are not the droids you're looking for`;
}

// Uncomment these to check your work! 
const starWars = ["Luke", "Finn", "Rey", "Kylo", "Droids"]
const thrones = ["Jon", "Danny", "Tyrion", "The Mountain", "Cersei"]
console.log(droids(starWars)) // should log: "Found Droids!"
console.log(droids(thrones)) // should log: "These are not the droi
```

Answer (score 1):

Just loop over the array and do the comparison

```js
function droids(arr) {
  let result = 'These are not the droids you\'re looking for';
  for(let i=0; i<arr.length;i++) {
      if (arr[i] === 'Droids') {
      result = 'Found Droid';
    }
  }
  return result;
}

// Uncomment these to check your work! 
const starWars = ["Luke", "Finn", "Rey", "Kylo", "Droids"]
const thrones = ["Jon", "Danny", "Tyrion", "The Mountain", "Cersei"]
console.log(droids(starWars)) // should log: "Found Droids!"
console.log(droids(thrones)) // should log: "These are not the droi





//A simpler approach 

console.log(starWars.includes('Droids') ? 'Droid Found' : 'These are not the droids you\'re looking for');
console.log(thrones.includes('Droids') ? 'Droid Found' : 'These are not the droids you\'re looking for');
```

Comment: That doesn't look like a for loop... "Complete the function droids that accepts an array of strings and iterates through the array using a FOR loop"

Comment: @Nick updated the answer, my bad

Comment: The question also specifically asks for the string `Droids`, and your code will match `Android`

Comment: Ironically it wasn't me that downvoted this post but since it now does work I'll at least balance it.

Comment: Sorry @Nick I didn't replied earlier due to time. Thanks for the correcting me as I learnt not to jump to answer quickly without reading the question carefully. Appreciate that :)

Comment: No worries - just trying to improve the overall quality of the site...

Answer (score -1):

```
function droids(arr) {
    result = "These are not the droids you're looking for." 
    
    for (str of arr) {
        if (str == 'Droids')
            result = "Found Droids!"
    }
    
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score -1):

> Follow this hope that you solve this problem.

```
const starWars = ["Luke", "Finn", "Rey", "Kylo", "Droids"];
for (i = 0; i < starWars.length; i++) {
  console.log(starWars[i]);
}
```